# How to synchronise my UILabel with the system time?

Tags: ios, swift, time

I have a label in which I want to show the system time. And I want my label to be synchronized with it i.e. the label will always show the same time as the time shown in the status bar.

I set the text of the label to the system time using this snippet:

```
let date = NSDate()
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm"
label.text = formatter.stringFromDate(date)
```

But I don't know when to run this code. I thought I can run it every minute, but that doesn't always work. Consider this:

The user starts the app at system time 08:00:30, the above code is run. The time shown in the status bar and the time shown in my label are the same: 08:00

At system time 08:01:00, the time shown in the status bar changes to 08:01. But since 1 minute has not yet passed since the start of the app, the label's text is still 08:00.

That's why I said doing it every minute doesn't always work.

I also thought of using an `NSTimer` to run that code every second or millisecond. But isn't that too excessive and will cause performance issues?

Is there a "proper" way to do this?

Comment: Great question. There seems to be notifications for when a "significant time change occurs" (UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification), but a minute hardly counts as significant does it :) I don't know the answer, sorry, but have you seen this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180920/nsnotification-when-device-time-changes-minutes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep calling your function every minute as you said but at the first time you can run it after 30 seconds (system time was 08:00:30) then continue calling after 1 minute and in that case I think they will be identical

Comment: Ah! So in `viewDidAppear`, I just need to figure out how many seconds until the next minute, and run the code after that many seconds. After that, I can use my 60 second `NSTimer` to do the updates. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

u could use `NSTimer` to refresh time every 60 second. Besides, for the first time refresh case, u could record how many seconds passed, and then set interval to second remaining

code might as follow:

```
 func refreshTime(firstRefresh: Bool) {
    let date = NSDate()
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm"
    let time = formatter.stringFromDate(date)
    print(time)

    var interval = 60.0

    if firstRefresh{
        let formatter_second = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter_second.dateFormat = "ss"
        let second = formatter_second.stringFromDate(date)

        interval = 60 - Double(second)!
    }
    let _ = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(interval, target: self, selector: #selector(GameScene.refreshTime(_:)), userInfo: false, repeats: false)

}
```